# Lightning Application Publisher Action

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, publisher-action

If I made a Lightning App or Component to view/manage a list **Foobar** objects, how would I go about adding an action like **New Foobar** to the Action Bar at the bottom of a page without using the Lightning App Builder itself to specify a publisher action? Can this be done/specified inside the aura:component/aura:application code itself?

For reference this behavior can be seen here:
https://youtu.be/XMK5Huuviow?t=223

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In its current beta implementation there is no way to hook Lightning Components into the publisher actions feature.

This will no doubt be part of some release in the near future as it is a key part of the Salesforce1 mobile UI.

But currently the only way to surface a Lightning Component in the S1 mobile UI is as a tab surfaced as an item in the left hand nav bar.

To take this a step further for just basic list-some-data and enter-new-data features it must be said that you can already do this in S1 mobile without lightning components. This is what the core page layout and declarative publisher actions give you without writing code.

Comment: Thats a shame, hopefully the **near future** is more near than far..

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of going the non-lightning component route to incorporate publisher actions, while I am not terribly familiar with that route I was aware. Although my example was just that; simplicity for the question at hand. My actual project involving Lightning Components is a bit more complex and requires me to stay in the Lightning Component realm.

Comment: I think a work around for the moment is to just add a button to call the controller to invoke a force:createRecord event itself then in the meantime, just will miss out on the native footer bar.